Windows Forms using PaintEvent leads to paint artifacts
I'm trying to make a function that highlights certain areas of a picture.
In practice this means that this function darkens the entire picture except for the desired areas. The positions and size of these areas are to be given as arguments.
I've made a proof of concept, which works but has some odd artifacts which I'm unable to get rid of. And I've got no idea why they are there. See picture below:

I've added two transparent areas, those are the areas you can see on the test picture.
But the artifacts to the left of the picture were not made by me (at least intentionally).
All of the code for this is in its own .CS file. (Except for the few lines that call the class of course...)
Designer:
partial class cComponentWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
     }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.btnOkay = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.StaticLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.DynamicLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.PCBPictureBox = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PCBPictureBox)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // btnOkay
        // 
        this.btnOkay.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 480);
        this.btnOkay.Name = "btnOkay";
        this.btnOkay.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(820, 23);
        this.btnOkay.TabIndex = 1;
        this.btnOkay.Text = "Okay";
        this.btnOkay.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnOkay.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnOkay_Click);
        // 
        // StaticLabel
        // 
        this.StaticLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.StaticLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.StaticLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(8, 2);
        this.StaticLabel.Name = "StaticLabel";
        this.StaticLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(130, 20);
        this.StaticLabel.TabIndex = 3;
        this.StaticLabel.Text = "Some Static Text";
        // 
        // DynamicLabel
        // 
        this.DynamicLabel.AutoSize = true;
        this.DynamicLabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.DynamicLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 25);
        this.DynamicLabel.Name = "DynamicLabel";
        this.DynamicLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 20);
        this.DynamicLabel.TabIndex = 2;
        this.DynamicLabel.Text = "Dynamic Text";
        // 
        // PCBPictureBox
        // 
        this.PCBPictureBox.InitialImage = null;
        this.PCBPictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 25);
        this.PCBPictureBox.Name = "PCBPictureBox";
        this.PCBPictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(790, 450);
        this.PCBPictureBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        this.PCBPictureBox.TabIndex = 4;
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form_Paint);
        this.PCBPictureBox.TabStop = false;
        // 
        // cComponentWindow
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(844, 511);
        this.Controls.Add(this.DynamicLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.StaticLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnOkay);
        this.Controls.Add(this.PCBPictureBox);
        this.Name = "cComponentWindow";
        this.Text = "Title";
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form_Paint); // I also tried commenting this auto generated one out. That didn't change anything.
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PCBPictureBox)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();
    }

    #endregion
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnOkay;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox PCBPictureBox;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label StaticLabel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label DynamicLabel;
}

Code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class cComponentWindow : Form
{
    // Variables:
    private UInt16 SizeX;
    private UInt16 SizeY;
    private UInt16 OffsetX;
    private UInt16 OffsetY;
    private bool[,] Matrix;
    private PaintEventArgs e;
    private Pen DarkPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(127, 0, 0, 0));

    // Methodes:
    public cComponentWindow(UInt16 OffsetX, UInt16 OffsetY, UInt16 SizeX, UInt16 SizeY, String CHK, Image Picture)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.OffsetX = OffsetX;
        this.OffsetY = OffsetY;
        this.SizeX = SizeX;
        this.SizeY = SizeY;
        this.DynamicLabel.Text = CHK;
        this.PCBPictureBox.Image = Picture;
        this.Matrix = new bool[this.SizeX, this.SizeY];
    }

    private void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }

    private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.e = e;
        this.Draw();
    }

    public void Highlight(UInt16 OffsetX, UInt16 OffsetY, UInt16 SizeX, UInt16 SizeY)
    {
        for (UInt16 x = 0; x < SizeX; x++)
        {
            for (UInt16 y = 0; y < SizeY; y++)
            {
                this.Matrix[OffsetX + x, OffsetY + y] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Draw() // OG time: 2m20s after some optimisations 0.5s (-99.6%)
    {
        //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), 0, 27, 790, 395 + 27);
        // Go through the entire matrix.
        for (UInt16 y = 0; y < this.SizeY; y++)
        {
            UInt16 StartBlock = 0;
            bool PreviousValue = false;
            for (UInt16 x = 0; x < this.SizeX; x++)
            {
                bool CurrentValue = Matrix[x, y];
                if (CurrentValue && !PreviousValue)
                {   // Draw the line to a highlight.
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(DarkPen, this.OffsetX + StartBlock, this.OffsetY + y, this.OffsetX + x - 1, this.OffsetY + y);
                }
                if (!CurrentValue && this.SizeX - 1 == x)
                {   // Draw the line to the edge of the screen.
                   e.Graphics.DrawLine(DarkPen, this.OffsetX + StartBlock, this.OffsetY + y, this.OffsetX + x, this.OffsetY + y);
                }
                if (PreviousValue && !CurrentValue)
                {   // Mark the start of the line.
                    StartBlock = x;
                }
                PreviousValue = CurrentValue;
            }
        }
    }
}

Which gets called by:
// x Offset relative to top left of the picturebox, y Offset relative to top left of the picturebox, width of the photo <= picturebox width, height of the photo <= picturebox height.
cComponentWindow Window = new cComponentWindow(0, 27, 790, 395, "Text to be dynamically displayed", global::G458.Properties.Resources.Test_Picture);
// x Offset relative to top left of the darken area, y Offset relative to top left of the darken area, width of the highlight <= darken area width, height of the highlight <= darken area height.
Window.Highlight(10, 10, 250, 150);
Window.Highlight(500, 300, 100, 50);
Window.ShowDialog();

In the first line of the Draw() function there is a fill commented out. This FillRectangle() command generates a similar artifact as the darken artifact. If you are trying it for yourself I suggest using that line of code once.
What I've tried doing:

Moving / resizing the darken area > Artifact changes shape but still exists.
Moving the PaintEvent to the window instead of the picture box. > Gave the exact same result.
Commenting out the PaintEvent on the window so only the PictureBox has the PaintEvent. > Gave the exact same result.

I don't know how I could fix this and would appreciate any fixes or suggestions :)
If you require some more information, please ask. I'll try to answer it as best as I can.
EDIT:
I managed to get it working correctly. I don't know precisely what I did to fix it. I had given up on trying to fixing the graphical glitch, it was not worth my time for this proof of concept. So I continued adding features and tweaking it. And somewhere during that process it got fixed. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me, I appreciate it.

Does cComponentWindow really not have a base class?  I was expecting class cComponentWindow : Form

@Wyck woops! That should have been there, I've accidentally removed it somehow while formatting this post. Fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Why do you have this thing: private PaintEventArgs e;, then you're doing this: this.e = e; this.Draw(); instead of the obvious this.Draw(e);? Are / were you calling Draw() from somewhere else, and you don't / didn't know what graphic object to pass? Have you omitted anything else, besides cComponentWindow : Form, which, BTW, is now added to the Designer file instead of the main file + your Form has no default Constructor -- Were you trying to obfuscate the Image with, say, a progressive curtain? Is the text already drawn inside an image? What are you trying to highlight?

@jimi it didn't occur to me that your solution would be possible. I will change that, thanks! And I see I did my fix in the wrong place. I've now "fixed" my fix.

It is supposed to show a picture of a PCB. I want to be able to highlight certain areas (components) of that PCB, to point out locations of interest.

For your use case, I recommend not using Paint on the Form, but use your source Bitmap to create a new Bitmap, and a PictureBox to display that.  Or use the Paint event of a PictureBox.  Your problems likely come from trying to paint over the area of other child windows, which is something you should try to avoid doing.

Write new code, paint on the surface of the PictureBox only (why you're using the Paint event of a Form is difficult to understand). Draw translucent rectangles (use colors with an alpha). If it fails, post that code. No need for the Designer file, it's irrelevant. Explain what the coordinates are related to and how these are calculated, in relation to what is shown in the picture

@BenVoigt That was the first thing I considered. But then I have to make and store 15+ photos per PCB. And this pop up window is going to be used for more then one PCB, which makes it not the best solution in my opinion.

@OADINC: You can still do the highlighting in code.  Use Graphics.FromImage() to paint into a bitmap.
